# Inheritance in Python for variable that's not parameter

Tags: python, class

In Python, I'm using inheritance for a class. The initial init for the main parent class is below:

```
def __init__(self, Date = None):
    self.Date = Date
    self.DatabaseClass = Database()
    self.Connection = self.DatabaseClass.databaseConnection()
```

I've inherited the class into the child class, but am wondering what the correct approach would be to inherit `DatabaseClass` and `Connection` variables, i.e., what would be in `def __init__`?

Comment: What inheritance do you mean? I only see composition

Comment: Could you show the definition of the classes?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call the inherited `__init__` method from your own class's `__init__` method.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, Date=None, other, arguments):
        super().__init__(Date)
        # ...
```